# p:calender minimum date validation, Date To < Date From

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I have Calender in my Filter component :

```
<p:outputLabel for="regCalendar" value="#{msg.registry_date}:" />
        <h:panelGrid id="regCalendar" columns="3">
            <p:calendar id="filterRegistryDateFrom" size="13" binding="#{filterRegistryDateFromComponent}"
                        value="#{commonDocumentController.registryDocumentsFilter.registryDateFrom}" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"
                        timeZone="#{notaryClientController.getLtTimeZone()}" maxlength="10" mask="true" 
                        pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" maxdate="#{now}" yearRange="c-120:c+30" navigator="true">
            </p:calendar>
            <p>-</p>
            <p:calendar id="filterRegistryDateTo" size="13" 
                        value="#{commonDocumentController.registryDocumentsFilter.registryDateTo}"
                        placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" timeZone="#{notaryClientController.getLtTimeZone()}" 
                        maxlength="10" mask="true" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" maxdate="#{now}"
                        yearRange="c-120:c+30" navigator="true">
            <f:attribute name="filterRegistryDateFromComponent" value="#{filterRegistryDateFromComponent}" />
            </p:calendar>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

I need to make dates validation, I could make JavaScript validation just to give message, when user wants to search by date and to use `registryDateTo` < `registryDateFrom` .. But what I want to achieve, when user choos date `registryDateFrom` it would automaticaly become the MINIMUM date in `registryDateTo` field.

So, for example, if I pick date  `registryDateFrom > October 15` ,so automatically user wouldn't be able to choose `registryDateTo < 15`

Comment: Just do `mindate="#{commonDocumentController.registryDocumentsFilter.registryDateFrom}"` and ajax-update it on change?

Comment: Like a charm. ! 

Thanks Balus.